# How to get a best-fit line on a scatterplot?

Tags: plotting, syntax

I know that I am supposed to call `ListPlot` inside of the `Show` function, but I can't seem to get that to work. The best I can get is this, which has the best-fit line following the scatter plot. How do I get the fit line to display on top of the scatter plot?

```
theTemps = WeatherData["Grossschwabhausen", "MeanTemperature", {{1956}, {2016}, "Year"}];
GrossschwabhausenTempByYear = Table[theTemps[[i]][[2]], {i, 59}];
ListPlot[miamiTempByYear, Joined -> False, Filling -> Axis, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesLabel -> {"Years from 1956", "Celsius"}]
Fit[GrossschwabhausenTempByYear, {1, x}, x]
Plot[%, {x, 2, 59}]
Show[%, {x, 2, 59}]
```

Comment: You could just do `ListPlot[theTemps, AxesLabel -> {"Years from 1956", "Celsius"}, Filling -> Axis]`. But, why are you fitting a line to a manifestly nonlinear trend?

Comment: The line does show a trend - 6.400613676212742` + 0.031793103448275836` x.

Comment: So you really need a picture like [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/E2iSP.png)?

Comment: Yes! That's perfect! How did you do that?

Answer (score 8):

The result returned by `WeatherData[]` is a `TimeSeries[]` object. `ListPlot[]` can deal with it directly, but `LinearModelFit[]` needs some assistance to handle it, since it cannot directly deal with either `TimeSeries[]` or `Quantity[]` objects. Thus:

```
trendLine = LinearModelFit[theTemps["Path"] // QuantityMagnitude, x, x]

Show[ListPlot[theTemps, AxesLabel -> {"Years from 1956", "Celsius"}, Filling -> Axis], 
     Plot[trendLine[x], {x, theTemps["FirstTime"], theTemps["LastTime"]}]]
```

[image: time series with trend line]

---

As noted by Jim, you can use `DateListPlot` to have years on the horizontal axis:

```
Show[{DateListPlot[theTemps, Joined -> False, Filling -> Axis],
      Plot[trendLine[x], {x, theTemps["FirstTime"], theTemps["LastTime"]}]}]
```

[image: time series on DateListPlot, with trend line]

(Note the extended date range as well.)

Comment: You are amazing thank you!

Comment: When I try to run your code I get this error: LinearModelFit::notdata: The first argument is not a vector, matrix, or a list containing a design matrix and response vector. >>

Comment: `theTemps` is the same thing in your question. What exactly did you change inside `LinearModelFit[]`? (Now that I think about it: what version are you on?)

Comment: version 9.0.1.0 It's a remote desktop to the school Mathematica

Comment: Tsk, you should have mentioned you were on an older version. What does `Shallow[theTemps]` return?

Comment: theTemps = 
  WeatherData["Grossschwabhausen", 
   "MeanTemperature", {{1956}, {2016}, "Year"}];
trendLine = LinearModelFit[theTemps["Path"] // QuantityMagnitude, x, x]

Show[ListPlot[theTemps, AxesLabel -> {"Years from 1956", "Celsius"}, 
  Filling -> Axis], 
 Plot[trendLine[x], {x, theTemps["FirstTime"], theTemps["LastTime"]}]]

Comment: I've never used Mathematica before and this project had to be done in two weeks during a summer semester. Shallow[theTemps] returns this: {{{<<3>>}, 6.37}, {{<<3>>}, 8.36}, {{<<3>>}, 8.18}, {{<<3>>}, 
  8.71}, {{<<3>>}, 7.96}, {{<<3>>}, 7.31}, {{<<3>>}, 5.29}, {{<<3>>}, 
  5.48}, {{<<3>>}, 6.52}, {{<<3>>}, 5.94}, <<50>>}

Comment: OK, try `trendLine = LinearModelFit[Flatten /@ theTemps, x, x]` instead.

Comment: It gives this error: LinearModelFit::fitc: Number of coordinates (3) is not equal to the number of variables (1). >>

Comment: (As you can probably tell it is hard for me to quickly diagnose your problem since I do not have version 9.) In that case, I am hoping `trendLine = LinearModelFit[MapAt[AbsoluteTime, theTemps, {All, 1}], x, x]` should work. Otherwise, I'm out of ideas, and you should wait for somebody with version 9 to come along.

Comment: Yes, Masheen, @J.M. is amazing. Using `DateListPlot` would show the year and adding in a plot of the prediction and/or confidence bands would be helpful for interpreting the seriousness of the line (although still not accounting for the likely serial correlation).

Comment: @Jim, maybe you can convince the guy. Admittedly I had forgotten about the possibility of serial correlation, but even with that caveat, I am not seeing a "secular" trend, and was thus skeptical of the need to put in a trend line.